# Let $G$ be a finite group and $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. If $H$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$, then $\exists g \in G$ s.t. $gHg^{-1} \leq P$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I want to show that

Let $G$ be a finite group and $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. If $H$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$, then there exists a $g \in G$ such that $gHg^{-1} \leq P$.

My attempt was:

By Sylow's first theorem, we know that there exists $P_{H}$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup containing $H$.
Then, by Sylow's second theorem as $P_{H}$ and $P$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ then both are conjugate, that is for $g\in G$ that $g P_{H} g^{-1}=P$, in particular $g H g^{-1} \subseteq P$

But, how do I conclude from this that it is a subgroup? which is what is being asked for

Comment: Conjugate to a subgroup is a subgroup.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3566872/sylow-theory-ghg-1-leq-p?rq=1